# how to use parameter from script into url_for at runtime and pass parameter

Tags: html, jinja2

The   section has event handler (dropdown onselect) that loads selected value from the dropdown into variable (var prjid = document.getElementyById().selectedIndex). How can this parameter (prjid) be used in an anchor tag; code 
      
fails as the value of prjid is not available.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What are you trying to do? Are you trying to create an anchor tag? Scroll to an existing anchor?

Comment: My html had a drop down that lists all the projects. On selecting one of the project, and hitting button named "Export", I wanted to export the selected project. I can perform this operation now with drop down selection event handler modifying the href of "Export" button's anchor tag by passing the project id to it.